# How to access values of footer textboxes on Button Click Event(Button is outside the Gridview)

Tags: asp.net

How to access values of footer textboxes on Button Click Event(Button is outside the Gridview)...Footer Text Boxes are generated dynamically in Dynamic GridView...... Footer Text Boxes may be very depending on Column in Table[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you have given id to your textboxes, you can access them using below code inside youe button_click handler.

```
TextBox txt = (TextBox) this.GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("textbox1");
```